# Strange off-by-one issue with snippet to generate gradients

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gradient

I use my own library for a lot of stuff, and recently I decided to add gradient functionality, but I've encountered a problem that I seem to remember having a while ago also, and this is the matter of my gradient being slightly off near the end. First, the code in question:

```
gradient = function(l, g)
 {
var r = [], s = [], f = g.length - 1;
for (var x = 0; x < g.length; x++)
    g[x] = (typeof(g[x]) == 'string' ? g[x] : g[x].join(','))._replace(['#', ' ', 'rgb(', ')'], ''),
    g[x] = (g[x].indexOf(',') != -1
        ? g[x].split(',')
        : g[x].chunk(2).map(function(_)
         {
            return _.fromBase('hex');
         }));
for (var x = 0; x < f; x++)
    s[x] = [(g[x][0] - g[x + 1][0]) / (l - 1) * f, (g[x][1] - g[x + 1][2]) / (l - 1) * f, (g[x][2] - g[x + 1][2]) / (l - 1) * f];
for (var x = 0; x < l; x++)
    r[x] = '', ([0, 1, 2]).map(function(_)
     {
        var c = Math.floor(x / (l / (g.length - 1)));
        r[x] += (g[c][_] - s[c][_] * (x - (l / (g.length - 1)) * c)).toBase('hex').pad('0', 2);
     });
return r;
 };
```

And, of course, my library: http://wimg.co.uk/HJ0X8B.js

Have fun in there! : ) If you think you might be able to help in any way at all, the custom functions I use in the gradient snippet are _replace(), chunk(), map(), and toBase() and fromBase()... as you'll be able to see at [this demo page](http://howironique.myartsonline.com/grad_t.html), everything pretty much works (at least in Opera and Firefox) save for the gradient being ever so slightly off at the end (hover to be shown the hex value). For example, calling `gradient(50, ['ffffff', 'ffff00', '00ff00'])` does indeed create an array of length fifty that contains hexadecimal color values gradually shifting from red to yellow and then to lime, however the last color isn't exactly lime (in this case, it comes out 05ff00); this means that there's something slightly off in the mathematics and not the methodology.

So... anybody willing to wade through the jungle that is the code I find so strangely beautiful to help me arrive at a solution? All assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The demo page link didn't work for me in FF 3.0.8

Comment: To clarify, the demo didn't appear to do anything when I clicked "generate"

Comment: As apphacker said. Your code is unreadable, please use meaningfull variable names instead of just naming them a random letter.

Comment: God, that was terrible; I left the link to my library as the one I use for my own server. Should work now... : ) And, Pim, they're not entirely random; the library's for my own personal use, so I tend to just pick letters that make sense to me: [r]eturn, [s]teps, [g]radient, [f]ade count...

Comment: Yeah, and look how many answers it's gotten you. :/

Comment: Demo is working now - Can you specify a width and height over which to set the gradient?

Comment: Some comments would be nice also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gradient = function(l, g)
 {
var r = [], s = [], f = g.length - 1;
for (var x = 0; x < g.length; x++)
    g[x] = (typeof(g[x]) == 'string' ? g[x] : g[x].join(','))._replace(['#', ' ', 'rgb(', ')'], ''),
    g[x] = (g[x].indexOf(',') != -1
        ? g[x].split(',')
        : g[x].chunk(2).map(function(_)
         {
            return _.fromBase('hex');
         }));
for (var x = 0; x < f; x++)
    s[x] = [(g[x][0] - g[x + 1][0]) / (l - 1) * f, (g[x][1] - g[x + 1][1]) / (l - 1) * f, (g[x][2] - g[x + 1][2]) / (l - 1) * f];
for (var x = 0; x < l; x++)
    r[x] = '', ([0, 1, 2]).map(function(_)
     {
        var c = Math.floor(x / (l / (g.length - 1)));
        r[x] += (g[c][_] - s[c][_] * (x - ((l-1) / (g.length - 1)) * c)).toBase('hex').pad('0', 2);
     });
return r;
 };
```

Use (l-1) instead of l on the last calculation line since you have prepared the s array for l-1 steps not l.

BTW your code is really hard to understand, try to write more understandable and standart code. And do write for loops instead of [0, 1, 2].map(sth).